# Find the limit or show that it does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit or show that it does not exist
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x ^4 + x^5 )$$

$∞ -∞$ is coming. I am stuck here.
The answer key says the answer should be $1/6$

Comment: @Af The "answer key" couldn't be more wrong...or else you wrote down a different expression. In yours, as in any rational function (including, of course, polynomials), the leading term is boss when talking limit of $\;x\to\pm\infty\;$ , and thus your limit here is $\;-\infty\;$ . Check carefully what you really meant to write...

Comment: Even though the question is written badly, you may want to use this hint $x^4+x^5=x^4(1+x)$

Comment: The only bounded polynomials are the constant polynomials, so the answer cannot be $\frac{1}{6}$, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

since $$x^4+x^5=x^5(\frac{1}{x}+1)$$ is the searched limit $$-\infty$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^4+x^5=x^4(1+x)$, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^4+x^5=\infty\times(-\infty)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer key is wrong:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x^4 + x^5)$$

$$= \lim_{x\to -\infty} x^5(1 + \frac{1}{x}) $$

$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty} x^5 \lim_{x\to -\infty}(1 + \frac{1}{x})$$

$$ = -\infty * 1 = -\infty$$